# mongoose findOne returns first object found even if condition is not true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using the MERN stack, I have a problem where mongoose findOne returns first object found even if condition is not true
This is my user model

```
{ local:{
username,
email,
password
},
google: {
googleId,
email,
name
}
}
```

I have this schema statics that find if email exists or not

```
userSchema.statics.findByEmail = async (email) => {
  const localUser = await User.findOne({ "local.email": email });
  const googleUser = await User.findOne({ "goolge.email": email });
  return { localUser, googleUser };
};
```

In my api before i add a user i search for it in my database using findByEmail

```
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findByEmail(req.user.email);
})
```

if there is no documents in my database, the api works perfectly but if there is at least one document, it always returns first document in my database even if  `req.user.email`
isn't in my database

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem happens in case in case the field is not declared in the schema where its being queried.

Please make sure that in your User Schema these fields exists: "local.email" and "goolge.email"

Comment: it was a typo mistake in ```goolge.email```, it is now fixed and working perfectly.

Comment: had this same error...

Comment: Anyone else think this is really dangerous behavior? Does anyone know if `deleteMany` works the same way?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey this is incredibly dangerous behavior. Can't believe this is the functionality.

Comment: saved hours lol